# Material UI add html to FormControlLabel

Tags: javascript, material-ui

in my project I need to customize a checkbox with FormControlLabel. In this label I need to show name and code of an item one above another with lowered font size. I tried to add html markup to label or used Typography, but it did not work. The code is as follows:

```
<FormControlLabel
      label={<Typography variant="subtitle2" style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: '10px' }}>{"name_here" + "<br />(\n also not working)" + "code_here"}</Typography>}
      control={<Checkbox size="small"/>}
/>
```

Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the sx property in the `FormControlLabel` for MUI V5. Alternative ways is to use styled components, or if you want a global solution to use the MUI theme.

Below is a solution using the `sx` and here is the working [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-cloud-dswyfn?file=/demo.tsx:513-970) to play with

```
    <FormControlLabel
          value="top"
          sx={{
            ".MuiFormControlLabel-label": {
              fontSize: "10px"
            }
          }}
          control={
            <Checkbox
              name="test"
              value="test"
              checked={true}
              size="small"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "controlled" }}
            />
          }
          label="Top"
          labelPlacement="top"
        />
```

Alternatively, if you want to render a `Typography` component in side the label you can write similar as you did

```
label={
    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: '10px' }}>
      Label Text
    </Typography>
  }
```

or give any properties you want in the `Typography` component